# Deploying from xamarin android to samsung s3 jellybean 4.1

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Hi guys I have some questions regarding deploying apps from Xamarin for Android. I have a samsung s3 with jellybean 4.1 in it and I want to deploy my app that I developed from Xamarin to my phone. But my problem is I do not know how to deploy it on a jellybean 4.1 OS. We have tried ice cream sandwhich before but jellybean is something I'm not even sure about whether it is supported by Xamarin for android or not? Is it possible to deploy my app in my phone? And anyone of you guys who knows how to do it??? I'd appreciate the help thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy to the S3 running JellyBean 4.1 (we are using one for testing).

Install the Samsung Kies manager on your dev machine so that you can get the latest device drivers.  If your phone still doesn't come up as an option when debugging your code then make sure that USB Debugging is enabled on the device.

Also, make sure that your application is targeting the Android version you want at a minimum (right click the project -> Properties... -> Application -> Minimum Android to target).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in procedure for deploying an app to Ice Cream Sandwich vs Jelly Bean.

Make sure your app's target SDK version is API 16 (API 17 if you want JellyBean 4.2). Follow the instructions I posted here to get the correct ADB drivers installed. [Samsung ADB driver installation via Samsung Kies](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2677/samsung-galaxy-note-10-1-not-detected-by-xamarin-studio/p1)

Also make sure you have the Jelly Bean SDKs installed by opening Android SDK Manager. If the SDKs for APIs 16 & 17 are not installed you will need to install them.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same procedure to deploy to a Jellybean phone.
You just have to make sure your phone has USB debugging activated, it's usually found in the "Developer Options" part of the settings, which must be enabled before you can activate USB debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not debugging on the device, make sure you set Build Configuration to Release so you get the Xamarin runtimes.